# Не работает свойство Children.Clear() C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

в ходе разработки приложения понадобилась генерация элементов управления кодом, но дилемма в том, что после этого невозможно очистить контрол. Данную проблему покажу на простом примере, чтобы не ухудшать восприятие. И так, допустим, что класс функция `Btn()` класса `Generate` отвечает за авторизацию пользователя и при нажатии кнопки должно меняться оформление окна (Добавиться новые элементы и исчезнуть кнопка).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public void Clear()
    {
        ClearChildControl();
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Generate generate = new Generate();
        MainGrid.Children.Add(generate.Btn());
    }

    public void ClearChildControl()
    {
        MainGrid.Children.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("Clear");
    }

}

public class Generate
{

    public Button button = new Button();
    public Button Btn()
    {
        button.Content = "Я кнопка";
        button.Padding = new Thickness(5);
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        button.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.ClearChildControl();
        };

        return button;
    }
}
```

Comment: `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();` этот код создает второе окно. Второе окно никак не связано с вашим главным окном. Вы очищаете далее второе окно, а главное ваше окно остается без изменений. Второе окно Вы создаете, но не отображаете, поэтому оно визуально не показывается.

Comment: Какая же очень глупая ошибка, даже стыдно стало) Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, на здоровье